Problem with @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI app to accept Stripe Payments
I am getting a runtime error of "Thread 16: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Order found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Order may be missing as an ancestor of this view." in the code for StripePaymentHandler on this line "configuration.defaultBillingDetails.email = order.email".  The code for StripePaymentHandler is below.   SecondView has a form that gathers order data including email address and then sends the order info to StripePaymentHandler that creates the Stripe paymentIntent
import StripePaymentSheet
import SwiftUI

class StripePaymentHandler: ObservableObject {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    @Published var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet?
    @Published var showingAlert: Bool = false
    
    private let backendtUrl = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxx")!
   
    private var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
    private var clientSecret = ""
    var paymentIntentID: String = ""
    
    var alertText: String = ""
    var paymentAmount: Int = 0
    
    func preparePaymentSheet() {
        // MARK: Fetch the PaymentIntent and Customer information from the backend
         
        let url = backendtUrl.appendingPathComponent("prepare-payment-sheet")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data,
                  let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                  let customerId = json["customer"] as? String,
                  let customerEphemeralKeySecret = json["ephemeralKey"] as? String,
                  let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String,
                  let paymentIntentID = json["paymentIntentID"] as? String,
                  let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String,
                  let self = self else {
                // Handle error
                return
            }
            
            self.clientSecret = clientSecret
            self.paymentIntentID = paymentIntentID
            print("I got the paymentIntentID from prepare-payment-sheet = ", self.paymentIntentID)
            STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = publishableKey
            
            // MARK: Create a PaymentSheet instance
            configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Gee-Ware"
            configuration.customer = .init(id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret: customerEphemeralKeySecret)
           
            configuration.defaultBillingDetails.address.country = "US"
            configuration.defaultBillingDetails.email = order.email
            configuration.billingDetailsCollectionConfiguration.attachDefaultsToPaymentMethod = true
            configuration.allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
            configuration.primaryButtonColor = UIColor(red: 0.70, green: 0.54, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1.0) //Color(red: 179 / 255, green: 140 / 255, blue: 237 / 255)
            configuration.applePay = .init(
              merchantId: "merchant.com.your_app_name",
              merchantCountryCode: "US"
            )
            configuration.returnURL = "your-app://stripe-redirect"
        })
        task.resume()
    }

Here is the Order class code
import Foundation

class Order: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var streetAddress: String = ""
    @Published var city: String = ""
    @Published var state: String = ""
    @Published var zip: String = ""
}

And the code for SecondView
import SwiftUI
import StripePaymentSheet

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    @State private var isLocked = true
    @State private var isLoading = false
    let layoutProperties:LayoutProperties
    @State var readyForPayment: Bool = false
    @FocusState var textFieldFocused: Bool
    @StateObject var model = StripePaymentHandler()
    @EnvironmentObject var gloVars: GlobalVars
    @State private var enteredNumber = "" //$99.66
    var enteredNumberFormatted: Double {
        return (Double(enteredNumber) ?? 0) / 100
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ResponsiveView { properties in
            VStack {
                Text("Slide to start payment process, hit button to confirm payment amount, then enter your payment details and your book is on its way to you")
                    
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Name", text: $order.name)
                        TextField("Email Address", text: $order.email)
                        
                    }

                    Section {
                        TextField("Street Address", text: $order.streetAddress)
                        TextField("City", text: $order.city)
                        TextField("State", text: $order.state)
                        TextField("Zip", text: $order.zip)
                    }
                }
                //Spacer()
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        BackgroundComponent()
                        DraggingComponent(isLocked: $isLocked, isLoading: isLoading, maxWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding()
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                .onChange(of: isLocked) { isLocked in
                    guard !isLocked else { return }
                    readyForPayment = true
                }
                Spacer()
               
                if let paymentSheet = model.paymentSheet {
          
                    PaymentSheet.PaymentButton(
                        paymentSheet: paymentSheet,
                        onCompletion: model.onPaymentCompletion
                    ) {
                        payButton
                    }
                }
                
            } //end vstack
        }//end responsiveview
        
        )
        .alert(model.alertText, isPresented: $model.showingAlert) {
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
        }
        
        .onChange(of: readyForPayment) {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
                    model.updatePaymentSheet()
                }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let priceAfterProfit = gloVars.bkAmount*100*gloVars.profitFactor
            enteredNumber = "\(priceAfterProfit)"
            model.paymentAmount = Int(enteredNumberFormatted * 100)
            model.preparePaymentSheet()
            textFieldFocused = true
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button("Done") {
                    textFieldFocused = false
                }
            }
            
        }
       
    }


You should not have @EnvironmentObject var order: Order in your StripePaymentHandler.
@EnvironmentObject is for use by Views only.
Note also, you should not nest ObservableObject. Try using @Observable instead. See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

@workingdogsupportUkraine how do I access the value in order.email from this line "configuration.defaultBillingDetails.email = order.email" in StripePaymentHandler then?

You could try this func preparePaymentSheet(order: Order) {....}.
I still recommend to use the more modern @Observable.

If you want to keep using ObservableObject try using struct Order: Identifiable {...}
and in your class StripePaymentHandler: ObservableObject { @Published var order: Order ...}.
No need for the @EnvironmentObject var order: Order in your SecondView,
use the one in the model.order .....
